# control is not going in the if part.(java in netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, netbeans, netbeans-7

i have made a jframe for login page,where the user have to provide the username and password press login button to log in.
for the validation i have given a if condition in the starting of the code in login_btnActionPerformed method,
teh codes in the method are:

```
private void login_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)       {                                          

String sql="select * from login where name=? and password=?";
if(name_field.getText()!=null && password_field.getText()!=null){   

try{
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, name_field.getText());
pst.setString(2, password_field.getText());
rs=pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "username and password is correct");
close();
NewPage n=new NewPage();
n.setVisible(true);  
}



else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "username and password is incorrect");
name_field.setText(null);
password_field.setText(null);

}
}


catch(Exception e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

}
}   
else
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter the username and password");
}
```

Now the problem is that when i am pressing the login button by keeping the the user_field and password_field blank ,then also its showing the popup(JoptionPane) dat username and password correct and its taking me to next jframe..
help me..

Comment: `if(name_field.getText()!=null && password_field.getText()!=null)` This will always be `true`. Side note: don't store passwords on database without hashing/crypting them

Answer (score 3):

Change `name_field.getText()!=null && password_field.getText()!=null` to `!name_field.getText().isEmpty() && !password_field.getText().isEmpty()`. That helps.

Answer (score 0):

check that the login table does not contain a row with name="" and password="" (empty values for those fields)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the `if` condition is not correct. As @alex2410 answer, you need to change the `if` condition as given by him or you can do it like this:

Replace

```
if(name_field.getText()!=null && password_field.getText()!=null){
```

By

```
if(name_field.getText().trim().length()==0 && password_field.getText().trim().length()==0){
```